# Problem with fluid width layout in IE 6 & 7

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18795563/blog/index.html
When resizing the window in IE 6, 7, and 8, This happens: http://img64.imageshack.us/i/aaawz.png/
It's fine when the window is Maximized, But when i try to resize it the sidebar gets pushed down at certain window sizes, It's fine most of time, But i still want to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your main section width to 74.99%

```
#main {
     width: 74.99%
}
```

Comment: This works, but in Firefox/Chrome, it becomes ~`1px` too narrow. It is only a minor issue. To fix it, I suggest using `width: 75%; *width: 74.99%`. With that, [only <=IE7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack) will be served the fix.

Comment: Make a conditional statement for specific css for IE only. Hacking css is not a good standard IMO.

Comment: Fixed the problem by making a conditional statement for IE 8 and earlier versions. I'm not sure if i need this fix for IE9 also?

Comment: Yes... I checked with IE9, and it also has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a float right and float left within the sidebar ID. Is this a fix of some sort?

For what it's worth Microsoft is actively trying to rid the world of IE6 as we speak. With only 5% of the world using it, most of whom are in China, you can pretty safely say that it's not necessary to provide the contingency.

Understandably that does not apply to the two more current versions but worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this its with media queries: 
here is an example of how to solve this, you can try with mobile, table and so on

```
<!-- Big screen -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" />

<!-- Tablet pc -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 799px)" />

<!-- Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />

<!-- If is lower than IE9 use conditional comments -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css" media="all" />
```

That's in case of IE doesnt work:
http://www.abovethefold.co.uk/blog/2008/09/23/css-ie7-compatibility-and-wordpress-updates/

And even a table that explain thouse issues:
http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries